Кинотеатр "Таллин": части речи
В русском языке нет compound nouns, как в английском. Выходит, что здесь два существительных: первое нарицательное, а второе собственное. Вопрос: как называются такие сочетания существительных в русском языке или как называется такая связь существительных и в какой книге об этом можно почитать подробнее?

"В русском языке нет compound nouns" -- это не так (хотя ваш пример не является составным существительным -- в этом вы правы).

Интернет-магазин, радиус-вектор, блокпост — чем не compound nouns?

Извините, я имел в виду существительное, между словами которого записываются пробелы.

Это называется «топонимы в сочетании с родовым словом».

https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/pismovnik/kak-sklonyat-geograficheskie-nazvaniya

Не скажу, как точно называется такая связь, но тип связи похож на примыкание, так как собственное в таком сочетании часто не склоняется: кинотеатр «Таллин», кинотеатра «Таллин».
При этом нарицательное (кинотеатр) называется родовым словом.
Про тип связи есть сомнения: в устойчивых сочетаниях (город Москва, колбаса «Докторская») собственное может согласовываться с нарицательным (родовым): в городе Москве, колбасы «Докторской».
